# unable to launch the configured development web server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

[image]

i have tried to repair from VS via "add or remove program" in control panel, but the error still appear..

> The first error appears when I try to update my VS

Comment: `The first error appears when I try to update my VS` does it means that you have an update that has failed? I had a similar experience when I clicked "cancel" during the installation of VS2012.3... I have to reinstall the whole computer to solve the issue :'( Even uninstalling the whole tools didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Backup data
2. Uninstall VS
3. Install VS

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the following procedure fixed it:

I have set the **Firewall** system manually. This means that, at the time of communication by programs Firewall notify me. Incorrectly linked to **"devenv.exe"** was blocked by the Firewall. Correct mode of communication "devenv.exe" will solve the problem. "devenv.exe" is located in the following path.

> "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0 \ Common7 \
>   IDE \ devenv.exe"

*Devenv lets you set various options for the integrated development environment (IDE), and also build, debug, and deploy projects, from the command line.*